# How to access foreign key values on MVC view?

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm having trouble accessing foreign key values in my view without using a partial.

I have tblProperty as Primary_Key and tblCustomer as foreign_key. I want to access the values of my foreign keys in my view but can't figure out why.

> Model

```
  public partial class tblProperty
{
    public tblProperty()
    {
        this.Images = new HashSet<Image>();
        this.tblCustomers = new HashSet<tblCustomer>();
    }

    public int propertyID { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblCustomer> tblCustomers { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class tblCustomer
{
    public int customerID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal contactNumber { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> propertyID { get; set; }   
    public virtual tblProperty tblProperty { get; set; }
}
```

> controller

```
 public class propertyController : Controller
{

    propertyDBEntities2 dc = new propertyDBEntities2();


    public ActionResult List()
    {

       var properties = dc.tblProperties.Include(p => p.tblCustomers);
        return View(properties.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        var properties = dc.tblProperties.Include(p => p.tblCustomers);
        tblProperty property = dc.tblProperties.Find(id);
        tblCustomer customer = dc.tblCustomers.Find(id);
        if (properties == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(dc.tblProperties.Find(id));
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(tblProperty e)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (dc)
            {
                dc.tblProperties.Add(e);
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

> view

(like model.name is trying to access name from tblCustomer)

```
 @model myProject.tblProperty
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Intellisense will tell you what properties you have available.

Comment: Its gives me an error on my view when I use @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)

Answer (score 0):

`tblProperty` doesnt have name.

I guess you need

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tblCustomer.name)
```

But just debug it or use intellisense

**EDIT:**

In my project I create a `dtoClass` *Data Transfer Object*

So for my `avl` class I have a `dtoAvl`

avl Class:

```
public partial class avl
    {
        public avl()
        {
            this.cars = new HashSet<cars>();
        }

        public long avl_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> car_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> speed { get; set; }

        // this class contain info regarding the road
        public virtual manila_rto manila_rto { get; set; } 
        public virtual ICollection<cars> cars { get; set; }
    }
```

I create a `dtoAvl`

```
public class dtoAvl
{
    public long Avl_ID { get; set; }
    public long? Car_ID { get; set; }
    public string RoadName { get; set; } // came from manila_rto 
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}
```

My controler

```
List<dtoAvl> result = db.avls.Select(
                              r => new dtoAvl
                              {
                                  Avl_ID = r.Avl_ID,
                                  Car_ID  = r.Car_ID,
                                  Speed  = r.Speed,

                                  // here is a propery but can be a list
                                  RoadName = r.manila_rto.name 
                              }).ToList();
return PartialView(result);
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<dtoAvl>
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but somehow my properties doesn't show up. I must be forgetting something.

Comment: did you try debuging?

Comment: yes, It looks like everything is done right I think I might need some connection or a different syntax on my view to access the foreign keys.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Because I got all that set up automatic for me.

Comment: yes. I made my database and like VS build my model. What does your view look like when your reference your model?

Comment: check my edit. I use a *Data Transfer Object* or `dto`